# using two tables with mysql

Tags: mysql

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `basic` WHERE id = 2 LIMIT 0, 30";
```

i want to retrieve data from 'users' table in the same query.
fields of users table are

1.country

2.name

3.userid

basic table consist of  selling items and there are unique id for each one.
also users table consist of  users and there are unique id for each one.

if  i say i want data from basic table where id is 4 and user's table where id is 15 in  same query....how should i rewrite above mysql statement

Comment: are both table any way related to each other? any FK?

Comment: what are the fields inside basic

Comment: no they  are not related

Comment: fields of basic table=id ,item,contactinfo

Comment: @chamara, if there is nothing is common in both table, then it's impossible

Comment: Above you've said that the 2 tables arent related in anyway, so if there is no link between them, you would have to use 2 separate queries, if there is a link such as userID in each, then you can do it as one.

Comment: @ diEcho  i just want to printout that data ain broswer

Comment: is it possible to use two queries in one php file?

Answer (score 3):

May be you need to read this [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).Try to read some tutorials that can help you improving your programming knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql=SELECT *
        FROM `basic` as b inner join `table2` as c
        WHERE b.id =c.id
```